# Can you respect a belief you don't agree with, and that you find morally reprehensible?

Tags: meaning

In in a debate with theist three words kept plaguing the conversation,

1. Respect
2. Agree
3. Understand

We were both satisfied with the communication using *agree*, and *understand*,

> *I understand what is happening, and the reasons for it but I don't agree with it.*

But, when *respect* was introduced all things went ape shit,

> *I understand what is happening, and the reasons for it but I don't respect it.*

How does *respect* relate to *agreement* and *understanding*? And, when speaking of moral matters can you ever *respect* something you find morally reprehensible?

Specifically, the context of this was

> Theologically, I can understand why Mormons deny Baptism to children of gay parents. But, even if homosexuality was a choice, I can neither agree with nor respect the notion of burdening a child because of the sins of a parents' choice.

The person I was talking to thought *not respecting* a religious tenant was wrong, and I can't figure out what kind of definition of "respect" you'd have to employ to make sense of that kind of statement.

Comment: Only if you can admire the reprehensible.  Can you?

Comment: When you don't  respect an opinion or a decision,  it means that you disagree, but you also add some moral connotation to your disagreement.

Comment: @deadrat no, so your contention is that respect is more related to admiration?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Nothing to do with me.  Admiration is part of the definition of respect.  You might prefer *revere* or *esteem*, but they're basically synonymous here.  They all have the concept of personally finding something worthy.

Comment: It is certainly possible to respect an enemy—even if "respect" in such a situation doesn't extend beyond the idea of "don't underestimate."

Comment: It depends on your definition of "respect", and to whom/what you are applying the term.  "Respect" has a whole spectrum of meanings.  (And you do not have to "admire" someone to "respect" them.)

Comment: @HotLicks I don't?  Says who?  Obviously, everyone is welcome to decide for themselves what they respect and how they respect it.  That doesn't mean that everyone gets to mandate that the word *respect* conform to some idiosyncratic definition.  The word means to have a positive regard for, a regard usually captured by the word *admire*.

Comment: @deadrat There is no contradiction when someone says they respect something they do not admire. "Respect" does not necessarily mean a positive regard for, or admiration for. It often simply means: "due regard for the feelings, wishes, rights, or traditions of others. synonyms: due regard, politeness, courtesy, civility, deference."

Comment: @MετάEd This is a different meaning of respect.

Answer (score 3):

*To respect* can be defined like this:

> 9. to hold in esteem or honor
> 10. **to show regard or consideration for**

(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/respect?&o=100074&s=t)

Seems to me you cannot honor or **hold in esteem** a belief you find morally objectionable, but you can show **consideration** for it.

For example, it's one thing **not to hold in esteem** what someone believes about infant baptism. It's quite another to walk into a place of worship during a baptism ceremony and show **disrespect** by disrupting the service.

Comment: This appears not to be the sense of *respect* the OP had in mind. For example, if parents think it wrong to give their child blood transfusions, a doctor is legally bound to respect that decision and not give a transfusion,  but may hold (and express) the view that the decision is wrong and reprehensible.

Comment: @Tim I think the example you give is actually identical in meaning to the one in this answer.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm not a mind-reader :) The word "respect" is a polysemant, that's what I highlighted in my answer. I think the answer to the OP's question is yes, you can respect a belief you find morally objectionable, even though you don't hold it in esteem.

Comment: But, you're defining respect now in your example by the lack of a show of *disrespect*.. That's Cartesian. I *will* consider every belief. That's part of the process of discarding it for a valid reason. Does that mean I respect everything that has entered my mind?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Arguably, yes, in a sense. Provided you allow a belief the courtesy of considering it, you show it a measure of respect.

Comment: That's a truly bizarre notion to me, and renders the use superfluous. Maybe that's why I've *never* heard it in that context. Perhaps that context is religious? Something akin to "*respecting* your parents" being a maxim, even if they molest and beat you? I wonder how that came to be? Trying to make sense of word that clearly doesn't belong, so it lost it's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Joe Blitv is a "thug", a "hood", who works for "the syndicate".  He's robbed banks, done a few kidnappings, and *maybe* (he's not saying) murdered a couple of people ("but if I did," he'll tell you, "they had it coming").

His current task is to place a bomb on a bus, timed to explode just as the bus is crossing a busy intersection, to create a diversion for a bank job.  This time of night no one is ever on the bus, other than the driver, and the bomb is in the back, so no one will get hurt.

But just as Joe leaves the bus the 20 kids of Mrs Smith's first grade class board the bus.  Seems they were in a "lock in" party at the school and had been out to see a movie, and are now returning to the school.  And they all want to sit in the back of the bus.

Joe can't have the death of 20 kids (and Mrs Smith) on his conscience, so, after exhausting all other options, he hops in his car, races to intercept the bus, and (relatively gently) collides with it.  He manages to shoo everyone off the bus and is trying to foist a suitable lie on the cops that then show up when the bomb goes off and the jig is up for Joe.

There is no way that I admire Joe, but I respect him for placing the interests of those kids ahead of his own.

Comment: This sounds like you do not admire Joe for being a thug, but you admire Joe for placing the kids' interest above his own. You're still using "respect" to mean "admire".

Comment: @A.P. - This just your opinion!  Do you expect me to respect or admire you for it?

Comment: (A) I expect neither. (B) Calling it "only my opinion" doesn't falsify it. (C) It's just *your* opinion that "this is just my opinion". The fact remains you *do* admire Joe for his selfless behavior. (Unless your definition of "admire" is totally idiosyncratic.)